# SQL Query with And & OR function

Tags: php, sql, database

I have four column `id`, `to`, `from`, and `name`

In one condition I would like to select rows where `to = $to` and `from = $from`.

In another condition I would like to also select rows where `from = $to` and `to = $from`.

How can I select both conditions in the same query.

Comment: Do you mean if _column_ `AND` _to_ equal `$to`?

Comment: sql supports `and` operator.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, this can be done like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE (column-to = $to AND column-from = $from)
OR (column-to = $to AND column-from = $from);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some databases support `in` with multiple columns:

```
where (`to`, `from`) in (($to, $from), ($from, $to))
```

This is database-specific.  The backticks are MySQL-specific.

Sidenote: Be careful when using SQL keywords and reserved words such as `from` and `to` .

Those require special attention, requiring them to be escaped in a way compatible with the database (typically backticks, square braces, or double quotes).

Comment: I (just) noticed (now) that the OP's question wasn't tagged as mysql, but just sql. I edited your answer Gordon about the reserved words. Please re-edit if you feel the word "MySQL" shouldn't be in there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- . . . A worthwhile warning.  I made it more general.

Comment: Yours does indeed make more sense Gordon, thanks. *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Simply group your `AND` conditions with parenthesis so that precedence is given to each set of conditions during evaluation.

```
SELECT something FROM table
       WHERE (to = $to AND from = $from) OR (from = $to AND to = $from);
```

Comment: sir here i can see Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\data.php on line 124